# Laravel - Return the manipulated value from a collection

Tags: php, laravel-5, methods, collections, return-value

I would like to manipulate a value from a collection! I receive the stylenumber as 12345-D-002. I have to explode this on "-" to have the first part of the stylenumber.

Collection-Code from Model Order:

```
public static function getPicklistToday($date)
    {
        $sql = "
            SELECT
                oxid_orderarticles.OXARTNUM as style,
                sum(oxid_orderarticles.OXAMOUNT) as ANZAHL,
                oxid_orderarticles.OXSELVARIANT,
                oxid_import.imported
            FROM oxid_orderarticles
            LEFT JOIN oxid_import
                ON oxid_import.oxid = oxid_orderarticles.OXORDERID
                WHERE DATE(oxid_import.imported) = :date
            GROUP BY oxid_orderarticles.OXARTNUM
            ORDER BY oxid_orderarticles.OXARTNUM ASC
        ";
        $pick = DB::select($sql,[':date'=>$date]);

        return $pick;
    }
```

This is the method, which should explode the returned 'style' from the query, also in Model Order:

```
    public function getParentStyle()
    {

        $parent = explode("-",$this->style);

        return $parent[0];
    }
```

Method in the OrderController:

```
    //------------------------
    public function today()
    {
        $today = Order::getPicklistToday(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));

        return view('order.today',compact('today'));

    }
```

Part of the view today.blade.php:

```
    @foreach($today as $pos)
    <tr>
      <td><i class="far fa-square"></i></td>
      <td><b>{{$pos->AMOUNT}}x</b></td>
      <td>{{$pos->getParentStyle()}}</td>
      <td>{{$pos->style}}</td>
      <td>{{$pos->OXSELVARIANT}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

I receive the following error message:

**Call to undefined method stdClass::getParentStyle() (View: /var/www/html/app/resources/views/order/today.blade.php)**

How should the method getParentStyle() look like to get my code running?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) here. Add this to your `Order` model:

```
/**
 * Get the parent style of the order.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getParentStyleAttribute()
{
    $parent = explode("-", $this->style);

    return $parent[0];
}
```

Now you can access the value like this:

```
<td>{{ $pos->parentStyle }}</td>
```

Comment: Sorry! Still got an error: ```Undefined property: stdClass::$getParentStyle (View: /var/www/html/app/resources/views/order/today.blade.php)```

Comment: Use `$pos->parentStyle` instead of `$pos->getParentStyle`.

Comment: Alright!!! Sometimes reading helps a lot!!! Thank you. Mutators were new for me. BUT, the table of my Order-Model doesn't have the style number in. The stylenumber is the table of the JOIN-Statment. Does this influence the functionallity of the mutator?

Comment: When the value `style` is in another table, this won't work. You would need a one to many relation between the parent model and the order model. Then you can show it like this: {{ $pos->parentModel->style }}. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many